# Can my app be decompiled to reveal string constants?

Tags: java, android, string, security, decompiling

I have a private API key in my Android app that is used in certain areas -- is there no way to prevent a user from somehow reverse-engineering or decompiling the Java to see what that key is? Is it not safe to put the key as a static field in a class? Is it safer to put it as a string resource in strings.xml? Or something else entirely? Or is it simply not possible to prevent a sufficiently motivated user from finding it?

Comment: this one: *it simply not possible to prevent a sufficiently motivated user from finding it* ... you may still obfuscate is somehow so it will not be avaible right after decompilation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding strings in Obfuscated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427238/hiding-strings-in-obfuscated-code) and [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949801/simple-hiding-obfuscation-of-strings-in-apk) too

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh: Good find.

Comment: if you using proguard then you can put it as String, proguard can protect your API key at a level.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for appreciation , just learning from great members like yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only *can* it be, it's not even hard.

You can make it *harder* by not storing it as a string at all, but as a series of numbers that you convert to a string at runtime (perhaps obfuscating it somehow).

But the answer to

> Or is it simply not possible to prevent a sufficiently motivated user from finding it?

is: Right, it's simply not possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more with the "series of numbers" example? I am okay with adding a few layers of protection even if it doesn't stop the most determined. I'd rather just not be low-hanging fruit.

Comment: @KaliMa: Well, that particular example probably would be fairly low-hanging. For instance, suppose your string were `"bqzT"`. You could store that as `int a1 = 0x5348e823; int b1 = 0x902b77b2; int c1 = 0xaff50d8b; int d1 = 0x2bf6eacc; int a2 = 0x5348e841; int b2 = 0x902b77c3; int c2 = 0xaff50df1; int d2 = 0x2bf6ea98;` and reconstitute it with `String s = new String(new char[] { (char)(a1 ^ a2), (char)(b1 ^ b2), (char)(c1 ^ c2), (char)(d1 ^ d2) });` Again: That's not particularly hard for someone to figure out, but the string won't be cleartext in your class file. :-)

Comment: So you define `a1` arbitrarily and then xor it with character `b` to get `int a2`?

Comment: @KaliMa: Yup. (I did it the other way around, but with xor it comes out the same either way. :-) )

Answer (score -1):

It is best to include your `String` as a constant in a class file and obfuscating it with `String obfuscation` and various other techniques using some free or commercial obfuscator. It's the best you can do and you will be fairly save. You can double-check yourself by decompiling and trying to find the key as if you didn't know it. You will see how good your protection is then.

Comment: Have you ever come across [Schneier's Law](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html)? Not being able to recover your own secret tells you nothing about whether others can.

Comment: @AndyTurner:
If you go through the obvious attacks and it looks hopeless you did a decent job at least. Of course it's not possible to guarantee nobody will ever succeed but some obfuscators are pretty brilliant at messing up decompiler outputs and the likes

Comment: Best hope those baddies stick to only using obvious attacks!